# Uniform convergence of $\varphi_n(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n(y-x))}{n(y-x)}f(y)dy$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$, we define
$$\varphi_n(x):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n(y-x))}{n(y-x)}f(y)dy\ .\ \ (x\in\mathbb{R})$$
(However, if $y=x$, it is interpreted as $\frac{\sin(n(y-x))}{n(y-x)}=1$.)

Proof that $\{\varphi_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(\theta)/\theta\,d\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1<sup>st</sup> proof.** Let $\operatorname{Leb}$ denote the Lebesgue measure. For any $\epsilon > 0$,

- there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\operatorname{Leb}(E) \leq \delta$ implies $\int_{E} |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x < \epsilon/2$, and
- there exists $N \geq 1$ such that $ \frac{2}{n\delta}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x < \epsilon/2$ for all $n \geq N$.

Then for any $n \geq N$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

\begin{align*}
\left| \varphi_n(x) \right|
&\leq \left| \int_{|y-x|<\delta/2} \frac{\sin(n(y-x))}{n(y-x)} f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right|
+ \left| \int_{|y-x|>\delta/2} \frac{\sin(n(y-x))}{n(y-x)} f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right| \\
&\leq \int_{|y-x|<\delta/2} \left| f(y) \right| \, \mathrm{d}y
+ \int_{|y-x|>\delta/2} \frac{2}{n\delta} \left| f(y) \right| \, \mathrm{d}y \\
& < (\epsilon/2) + (\epsilon/2) = \epsilon.
\end{align*}

Therefore $\varphi_n \to 0$ uniformly as $n\to\infty$.

---

**2<sup>nd</sup> proof.** Write

$$ S(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{\sin t}{t} \, \mathrm{d} t. $$

We know that $S(x)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $M > 0$ denote a bound of $S$, and write $C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$ for the set of all compactly supported $C^1$-functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Then for any $g \in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$,

\begin{align*}
\left| \varphi_n(x) \right|
&\leq \left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n(y-x))}{n(y-x)} (f(y) - g(y)) \, \mathrm{d}y \right| + \left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n(y-x))}{n(y-x)} g(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right| \\
&\leq \| f - g \|_{L^1} + \left| \frac{1}{n}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(n(y-x)) g'(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right| \\
&\leq \| f - g \|_{L^1} + \frac{M}{n} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |g'(y)| \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}

So, taking supremum over $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and taking limsup as $n\to\infty$,

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left( \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \left| \varphi_n(x) \right| \right) \leq \| f - g\|_{L^1}. $$

However, since the left-hand side is independent of $g$ and $C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, letting $g \to f$ in $L^1$ proves the desired claim.

Comment: (+1) for the well-thought and well-written solution.